PyVisa lists my ethernet connected device, but error when trying to open resource [python3.11]
I am trying to communicate with TTi power supply model QPX1200SP through ethernet connection.
Here is my script:
import pyvisa as visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
print(rm.list_resources(query='TCP?*')) #specific query for anything over Ethernet

#above line gives me an answer ('TCPIP0::10.10.0.27::9221::SOCKET',), so line below:

ttipsu = 'TCPIP0::10.10.0.27::9221::SOCKET'

psu = rm.open_resource(ttipsu)

I receive a traceback:

File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)
File c:\users\me\documents\python scripts\visa\pyvisa_v1.py:18
psu = rm.open_resource(ttipsu)


File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py:3291 in open_resource
res.open(access_mode, open_timeout)


File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\resources\resource.py:281 in open
self.session, status = self._resource_manager.open_bare_resource(


File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py:3216 in open_bare_resource
return self.visalib.open(self.session, resource_name, access_mode, open_timeout)


File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py:1850 in open
ret = library.viOpen(


File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\ctwrapper\highlevel.py:226 in _return_handler
return self.handle_return_value(session, ret_value)  # type: ignore


File C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\pyvisa\highlevel.py:251 in handle_return_value
raise errors.VisaIOError(rv)


VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_RSRC_NFOUND (-1073807343): Insufficient location information or the requested device or resource is not present in the system.

I also tried it with line:
rm = visa.ResourceManager('C:\\Windows\\System32\\visa64.dll')

I can ping the 10.10.0.27 with success, 2ms, 0% loss.

What seems to be a problem here?

After some research I have found that information in the manual (for this device) is misleading.
The device is Thurlby Thandar instruments (TTi) QPX1200SP.
The manual's info states, that user shall use (example)
TCPIP0::192.168.1.100::9221::SOCKET
instead of 'normal' VISA resource name of
TCPIP0::192.168.1.100::inst0::INSTR
When I replaced resource name to 'normal' VISA name, it begin to work correctly.
